# Physical pages offset check

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory, page-tables

The page table is used to translate from virtual to physical pages.
Assuming 4KB pages (PAGE_SHIFT=12), the address `0xA100` is composed of:

```
Virtual address:     0xA100
Virtual page number: 0xA
Offset:              0x100
```

The role of page table is to translate virtual page number (`0xA`) to the respective physical page number (let's say `0xB`).

Finally, since the offset is the same for both virtual and physical pages, the physical memory address is composed in the following way:

```
Physical address:     0xB100
Physical page number: 0xB
Offset:               0x100
```

I was wandering if, given a physical page, a process can access to all the addresses within the page? In other words,
after checking page permissions in the page table, are there any checks on the offset?

Answer (score 0):

No more checks on that.
If the virtual memory is organized in pages, a page is a unit of memory management.
OS always gives pages to a process. The process might organize it in some way. It can check the length of an array, or it can organize some chunks of memory like malloc. But the check handled by hardware and OS is only page-level. Inside a page, you need to do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you. So, for instance, if I allocate an array of 15 elements and I try to access to the 16th element who is responsible for checking?

Comment: @rrpp1045 In C or other language which doesn't check the boundary of array for you, if you are lucky(or unlucky, this stops you from finding the bug), the program might be running 'correctly' without immediate failure, or even never fails. You need to check it in your code, using assertion or simply 'if'.